# Rails: after_create callback triggered only on production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Anyone know why an after_create callback is triggered only on production environment ?

```
class Schedule < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :account

  validates :schedule_type, presence: true # default = 'appointment'

  after_create :send_notification, if: :devices_and_appointment?

  def devices_and_appointment?
    account_has_devices? && schedule_type.appointment?
  end

  def account_has_devices?
    !account.devices.blank?
  end

  def appointment?
    schedule_type.eql?('appointment')
  end
end
```

On production, the callback is triggered, even if schedule_type is not appointment. I check the logs and the controller receive the params as expected (schedule_type != appointment)

For a strange reason, when `after_create` is invoked, the schedule_type is the default.

We check this on development and even in staging env and we cannot reproduce the bug.
The differences between staging and production is the DB sharding (Octopus) but we only have this activated for reads, in some other controllers, not even in the `ScheduleController`

We end up moving the callback method to a service, calling the function after the `.save` and that fix the problem, but I still want to know why this happen.

Controller:

```
def create
    @schedule = Schedule.new(schedule_params)

    if @schedule.save
      render json: @schedule, status: 201
    else
      render json: { errors: @schedule.errors }, status: 422
    end
end

def schedule_params
   params
      .require(schedule)
      .permit(:account_id, :cause, :ends_at, :schedule_type, :starts_at)
end
```

Request:

```
Parameters: {"schedule"=>{"cause"=>"cause random", "starts_at"=>"2018-09-17T21:00:00.000-05:00", "ends_at"=>"2018-09-17T21:30:00.000-05:00", "schedule_type"=>"blocked", "account_id"=>"123"}}
```

Comment: Can you share the methods for `account_has_devices?` and `ScheduleType#appointment?`?

Comment: also show the request log, the controler, anything related

Comment: @MikeGorski i just added the methods

Comment: @arieljuod i just added the controller and request

Comment: Shouldn't `account_has_devices? && schedule_type.appointment?` be `account_has_devices? && appointment?`? `appointment?` is a method defined on the current object and I understand that `schedule_type` is just a string. Also, what are you doing with `validates :schedule_type`? it looks like it's missing the actual validations like "presence: true" or something like that.

Comment: Ok. I'm just trying to narrow it down and trying to understand what you are doing since some things are not clear at least for me. The rest of the code looks right (the parameters, the require/permit, etc).

Comment: @arieljuod yes, this is some small piece of code of my whole model, I've only put the validation to clarify that this attr exists and must be validated (presence).